# data-toggle=tab not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, coldfusion

I am trying to implement a tabbed heading on my page like below.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="abc.cfm" data-toggle="tab">page One</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="def.cfm">page Two</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="xyz.cfm">page three</a></li>                           
</ul>
```

Can I use this to navigate to a new page like shown above on the href? I looked up examples for this, but they show data switching from the same page, and not navigating to a another page.Any suggestion are appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Just take out the data-toggle and it should work as a normal link.

Answer (score 0):

*data* attribute itself does nothing. For your purposes you should add some javascript code. let's clean things up.

in HTML use *data-toggle* to store the id of the page you want to show

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li data-toggle="page1">page One</li>
    <li data-toggle="page2">page Two</li>
    <li data-toggle="page3">page three</li>                           
</ul>

<div class="page" id="page1">Content Page 1</div>
<div class="page" id="page2">Content Page 2</div>
<div class="page" id="page3">Content Page 3</div>
```

in Javascript show that page (based on the id of clicked element)

```
$('[data-toggle]').click(function(){
    $('.page').hide();
    var pageId = $(this).data('toggle');
    $('#'+pageId).show();
})
```

Check out this [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/sjaj39ue/)